# Finding the rate of water rising a vase with a square base and sloping sides

Tags: calculus

How do you solve this rates of change question?

> A vase with has a square base side length $6$cm and flat sides sloping outwards at and angle of $120^\circ$ with the base. Water flows in at $12\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$. Find the rate of the height of water rising for $3$ seconds.

So I have my volume formula
$$v = 36h + \frac{12h^2}{\sqrt3} \tag1$$
Also,
$$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{dh}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{12}{36+\frac{24h}{\sqrt3}}\tag2$$
since given $12\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$.

However, I am having trouble finding $h$. I tried using the condition that at $3 $ seconds, the volume is $=36$, but I get an incorrect value and hence incorrect answer when I sub it into the final $dh/dt$ equation.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are calculating volume may be leaving certain parts of it in the $4$ corners.

Please note that at height $h$, you get a square with side length of $6 + \frac{2h}{\sqrt3}$ ($\frac{h}{\sqrt 3}$ adds on both ends of each side).

So what you have is a truncated square pyramid and the volume is given by the below formula (or you have to calculate and add extra volume in $4$ corners) -

$V = \frac{1}{3}(6^2 + (6 + \frac{2h}{\sqrt 3})^2 + 6(6 + \frac{2h}{\sqrt 3}))h$

This leads to a cubic -

$V = \frac{4h^3}{9} + 4 \sqrt3 h^2 + 36h$

At $t = 3$,

$36 = \frac{4h^3}{9} + 4 \sqrt3 h^2 + 36h$

and leads to $h \approx 0.8525$.

Now $\frac{dV}{dt} = (\frac{4h^2}{3} + 8 \sqrt3 h + 36) \frac{dh}{dt}$

Can you take it from here?